# Where should I place the code to be executed each time a new User is created with django-registration?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am using django-registration. I have created a class named "Statistics" with a one-to-one relation with each instance of the class User.

Every time a new User is created via the /accounts/register page, I would like to be able to create a new instance of the class "Statistics" and associate it to the just created User.

My question is, where should I have to write the code to do that? Where should I place the code to be executed each time a new User is created? Something along the lines of:

```
s = Statisics ( comments = 0, thanked = 0, user = UserThatWasJustCreated)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by Josh, you should attach your code to a signal, except I would consider attaching it to [Django's `post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) if you need your code run even when a `User` is created outside django-registration.

In that case, it should be something like:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def create_statistic(sender, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created'):
        s = Statisics( comments=0, thanked=0, user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_statistics, sender=User)
```

You can place that code after your `Statistics` model definition.

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo for your detailed answer. This is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the custom signals that Django-Registration makes available: http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/signals.html. I think one of these will do the job for you.

Comment: Thank you Josh for your prompt response. You were absolutely right pointing me in that direction.